# L tetrominoes forming an 8x8 magic square

Tags: polyomino, magic-square

This is a puzzle from Rodolfo Kurchan.

Can you place 10 L-shaped [tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) on a 8x8 grid, such that:

- No two tetrominoes overlap.
- Tetrominoes can be rotated and flipped.
- Every row and column contains the same number of cells covered by a tetromino.

Comment: Can we used the flipped version i.e. J tetrominoes as well?

Comment: Yep. Just updated the conditions.

Comment: I made a more general version of this puzzle: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115341/sets-of-tetrominoes-forming-a-magic-square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to work out the number of squares in each row.

> Each tetromino takes up 4 squares, and each contributes twice to the total squares in rows and columns.
>
>  So each tetromino contributes 8 squares.
>
>  There are 10 * 8 = 80 squares and 16 rows/columns, so there are 80 / 16  = 5 squares per row/column.

Then, some trial-and-error does the trick:

> [image]

I started with this configuration, which looked promising:

> [image]

Then messed around until I found an inner configuration that worked.

An alternative, asymmetric solution:

> [image]

Comment: Awesome work! That is even more beautiful than the solution I had in mind.

Comment: I wonder if we can also get the two main diagonals to work, making it fully magic?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Hm... that wouldn't work with rotational symmetry, I'd have to mess around a bit more.

Comment: I think there might be some parity argument, as all the solutions for rows/columns that I've found have even numbers of squares on both diagonals.

Comment: @Ausername I've had a quick play with pencil and paper, and arrangements with odd diagonals do exist. Haven't found one with five on both yet.

Comment: @fljx Hm, interesting.

Comment: E.g. Starting with your asymmetric solution, if you mirror two of your tetrominos, you can reduce the count on the primary diagonal to 5 while maintaining all the row and column counts (R5C5->R5C7 and R6C7->R6C5)

Answer (score 2):

@Ausername has answered the main question, but an additional question was asked in comments:

> I wonder if we can also get the two main diagonals to work, making it fully magic?

And the answer to this is:

> **Yes**
>
>   The following is one example:
>  [image]

Comment: I love this! Well done.