# Sets of tetrominoes forming a magic square

Tags: polyomino, magic-square

Is it possible to place $n$ sets of five free [tetrominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) on a $K \times K$ square grid, such that:

- No two tetrominoes overlap.
- Tetrominoes can be rotated or flipped.
- Every row, column and two main diagonals contain the same number of cells covered by a tetromino.

What are the smallest positive $n$ and $K$ for which this is possible?

Comment: I have a solution, but it has a large $n$. Hopefully that can be reduced.

Comment: Just to clarify, the square grid can be arbitrary size? (independent of n).

Comment: What is the smallest *positive* n and K for which this is possible.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky just curious: how large was the *n* in your solution?

Comment: @Oliphaunt like 8, so it is not even worth discussing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does the trick:

> n=2, k=10
>  Each row, column and main diagonal has 4 cells covered.
>  [image]
>  Perhaps this can be improved, with the same tetrominos covering 5 cells per row/column/diagonal on an 8x8 square grid.

And with a bit of programming, we find this:

> n=2, k=8
>  Each row, column and main diagonal has 5 cells covered.
>  [image]
>  This is just one of several hundred solutions with the two square tetrominoes together in the top left corner. There are no doubt thousands of other solutions, but I did not optimize the search to enumerate them within any reasonable timeframe.

Comment: That's a great solution!

Comment: What about n=1 and K=5? Can we show that it's impossible?

Comment: A standard parity argument shows that an n=5,k=10 filled grid is impossible. (With checkerboard colouring, all but the T tetromino cover two black and two white squares each. So you need your five T tetrominos to cover the remaining 10 black + 10 white squares, which isn't possible when each covers 1 black + 3 white or 3 black + 1 white)

Comment: I have ruled out the n=1, k=5 case by essentially trying all possibilities for where the holes are. I don't have a neat argument for impossibility, though some are ruled out by a similar parity argument as above.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I have done exactly the same - ruling out n=1,k=5 using where the holes are. It is good to get a confirmation on this.

Comment: By the way, n=1, K=10 case is also impossible as the 1x4 tetromino will cover more than 2 cells in some row/column.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Optimal solutions found.

Comment: @DanielMathias you total legend! Well that saves me from coding it up :)